# cupy: Excessive memory usage with boolean indexing?

Tags: python, gpu, cupy

#### The current behavior:

```py
import cupy as cp

big = cp.zeros( (4_000, 4_000, 120), dtype=cp.float32)  # ~ 7.6 GiB
idx = cp.ones( (4_000, 4_000), dtype=cp.bool_) # ~ 16 MiB
b2 = big[idx]  # ~ 24 GiB
```

#### System:

- cupy: 11.6.0
- gpu: Nvidia RTX 3090 24 Gb

#### Expected behavior:

In this instance, where we are boolean indexing all of the items, I would expect the memory usage to at most double, not triple.

If we only index 7,000,000 items with `idx[:3_000, :3_000] = False` then the above code uses ~ 20 GiB

#### Numpy:

Duplicating the 3 lines of code with numpy API and tracking memory with:

```
import os, psutil
process = psutil.Process()
print(process.memory_info().rss)  # in bytes
```

We see that the numpy implementation only uses ~7.8 GiB of memory. So it looks like numpy is using a more efficient "view" of the data than cupy is.

#### Question:

Is the above behavior expected? Is there a more memory efficient "views" way of accomplishing the same thing in cupy?

Comment: Using `r, c = cp.where(idx)` and `b2 = big[r, c]` brings down the memory usage to ~ 15 GiB. Or the "expected" doubling of memory (instead of tripling by using boolean indexing).